# Neo4j Community detection

Tags: neo4j, graph-data-science

Hello Stack overflow community;
I am working in a scholar project using Neo4j database and i need help from members which are worked before with neo4j gds in order to finding a solution for my problem;
i want to apply a community detection algorithm called "Newman-Girvan" but it doesn't exist any algorithm with this name in neo4j gds library; i found an algorithm called "Modularity Optimization", is it the Newman-Girvan algorithm and just the name is changed or it is a different algorithm?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the newman-girvan algorithm, but the fact that it's a hierarchical algorithm with a dendrogram output suggests you can use comparable GDS algorithms, specifically Louvain, or the newest, Leiden. Leiden has the advantage of enforcing the generation of intermediary communities. I've used both algorithms with multigraphs; I believe this capability was just introduce with gdg v 2.x.

The documentation on the algorithms is at
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/

https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/alpha/leiden/

multigraph:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-project-cypher-aggregation/